# How do I show the standard page layout in salesforce lightning component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component which shows the same page layout for all the record Types currently but now I want to differentiate between the recordtypes and want to show  the same layout in the component for one recordtype Id but for other recordType Id, I want to show the standard pagelayout. So, which element would help me achieve that. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lightning:recordViewForm` component. This component handles different record types on its own. We just need to pass record id to it.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm/documentation

You can use `force:recordEdit` It will handle all conditions for edit.

Comment: I found out  that we can only use Lightning:output using this Lightning:recordViewForm component. My desire is to get the user to fill in the input layout fields and then save it

Comment: @user3920709 Please check force:recordEdit

Comment: I think I can use force:createRecord

Comment: So you want to create record.. I thought you want to edit record

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad. Yes, I want to create a new record

Comment: Yes force:createRecord is correct

Answer (score 0):

you can just create two different page layout and assign the page layout to record type based on your condition. You don't need to do any custom development.